# Virtual column based on current date

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is it possible to use the current date in virtual columns?

This is what I tried so far:

I've created the following migration.

```
Schema::create('contracts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->date('expires_at');
    $table->boolean('is_expired')->virtualAs('expires_at < CURRENT_DATE()');
});
```

Which outputs in the following query:

```
create table `contracts` (
    `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    `expires_at` date not null,
    `is_expired` tinyint(1) as (expires_at < CURRENT_DATE())
) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

The error message I am getting:

> Expression of generated column 'is_expired' contains a disallowed function.

So, I know you can't use virtual columns this way. Is there an other way to make this column generated? Maybe something with triggers?

Because I am using Laravel for this project, I would be happy with a PHP solution.

Maybe there is an options to put raw sql statements in the `$appends` array? That would also help. As long as I can execute `WHERE is_expired = false`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom attributes to your Laravel models. You just need to create a getter:

```
class Contract extends Model {
  public function getIsExpiredAttribute() {
    return (Carbon::now() > $this->expires_at;
  }
}
```

This way you can check whether a contract is expired by looking at the value of `$contract->is_expired`.

If you want that value to be returned with your models from the controllers, you'll need to put that attribute in `$appends` array:

```
class Contract extends Model {
  protected $appends = ['is_expired'];
}
```

If you want to filter non-expired contracts, you'll need to compare the expiration date and current date in your query:

```
$nonExpiredContracts = Contract::whereRaw('expires_at <= NOW()')->get();
```

If you need to use this constraint in multiple places, you can create a local scope in your model to let you avoid code duplications and make syntax clearer. First define the local scope:

```
class Contract extends Model {
  public function scopeNonExpired($query) {
    $query->whereRaw('expires_at <= NOW()');
  }
}
```

Now you can pick non-expired contracts with:

```
$nonExpiredContracts = Contract::nonExpired()->get();
```

Comment: In know you can do it this way. But I want to use the column in database query and `selectRaw()` methods. Not with my scope methods. That's because I make an api that appends where statements dependent on the `$_GET` parameters

Comment: As you could see, you can't have a column like that and will need to do that on the application level. BTW, check https://github.com/jedrzej/searchable package, it does exactly what you need - applies different filters to your queries depending on whatever came in the GET url. It will work out of the box for the database columns, you'll just need to add a simple function to Contract model to handle your virtual attribute: public function processIsExpiredFilter(Builder $builder) { $builder->nonExpired(); return true; }

Comment: I am looking for a way to make this possible in MySQL. I know how I can add attributes in Eloquent models.